# iOS Swift: Error loading timezone data from file system

Tags: ios, swift, ekevent, ekeventstore

I'm trying to fetch events from `EKEventStore` between the last year and the next three years but I got this error:

> Error loading timezone data from file system. This is a serious
>   problem. Calendar data is not guaranteed to be accurate.

If I change the lastYear date from adding -1 to 0, no errors are prompted

this is the code:

```
 struct TaskService: TaskServiceProtocol {

        let store: EKEventStore

        init(withStore store: EKEventStore) {
            self.store = store
        }
        func tasks() -> [TaskItem] {
            let calendar = Calendar.current
            let today = Date()
            let startDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .year, value: -1, to: today)!
            let endDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .year, value: 3, to: today)!
            let eventsPred = store.predicateForEvents(withStart: startDate, end: endDate, calendars: nil)
            let events = store.events(matching: eventsPred) as? [TaskItem] ?? []
            return events
        }
    }

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        requestAccess()
    }

    func requestAccess() {
        let store = EKEventStore.init()
        store.requestAccess(to: .event) { (granted, error) in
            let service = TaskService(withStore: store)
            let events = service.tasks()
            print(events.count)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I'm having the same issue, did you find a solution ? Thanks.